# Parsing Poorly formed JSON in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, nsdictionary

My task is to parse some JSON which was created by running an XML to JSON conversion tool on an XML WADL. I'm able to parse the data returned in the response into JSON and I'm able to obtain the top level NSDictionary from the data. I can get an array from the dictionary and an  NSDictionary from the Array ( it includes the key value but thats it) and thats as deep as I can go. I've done parsing in the past but this particular JSON format I am having no luck? Here is the code I'm using..

```
// Decode the data
NSError *parseError = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [request responseData];
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&parseError];
if (parseError) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [parseError localizedDescription]);

    // other stuff..
    return;
}

NSLog(@"JSON=: %@", responseDict.description);
NSArray *messageBoxResponse = [responseDict objectForKey:@"messageBoxResponse"];
NSLog(@"messageBoxResponse=: %@", messageBoxResponse);
NSUInteger count = messageBoxResponse.count;
for (NSDictionary* messages in messageBoxResponse) {

    NSLog(@"Messages=: %@", messages.description);
    NSArray *message = [messages objectForKey:@"message"];

    // get SIGABRT
    count = message.count;

    // If I comment out above line and introduce this I get SIGABRT also
    for (NSDictionary* something in message) {
        NSLog(@"Somthing=: %@", something.description);


}
```

Here is the JSON I'm attempting to parse.. IPs have been changed :):

```
{
messageBoxResponse =     {
    messages =         {
        link =             {
            href = "http://1.1.1.1:80/services/messageboxes/63358/messages";
            rel = self;
        };
        message =             (
                            {
                flags =                     {
                    answered = 0;
                    link =                         {
                        href = "http://1.1.1.1:80/services/messageboxes/63358/messages/<4F3131A3.6040204@sc-msg1-msg.sc.sc>/flags";
                        rel = self;
                    };
                    taggedForDeletion = 0;
                    unread = 0;
                };
                from = "Suren.1@sc-msg1-msg.sc.sc";
                link =                     {
                    href = "http://1.1.1.1:80/services/messageboxes/63358/messages/<4F3131A3.6040204@sc-msg1-msg.sc.sc>";
                    rel = self;
                };
                parts =                     {
                    link =                         {
                        href = "http://1.1.1.1:80/services/messageboxes/63358/messages/<4F3131A3.6040204@sc-msg1-msg.sc.sc>/parts";
                        rel = self;
                    };
                    part =                         {
                        link =                             {
                            href = "http://1.1.1.1:80/services/messageboxes/63358/messages/<4F3131A3.6040204@sc-msg1-msg.sc.sc>/parts/0";
                            rel = self;
                        };
                        mimeType = "TEXT/PLAIN";
                        name = "text.txt";
                        size = 564;
                    };
                };
                receivedDate = 1328624061000;
                sentDate = 1328624035000;
                subject = test;
            },
                            {
                flags =                     {
                    answered = 0;
                    link =                         {
                        href = "http://1.1.1.1:80/services/messageboxes/63358/messages/<24346739.35.1328562602976.JavaMail.mango@sc-msg1-msg.sc.sc>/flags";
                        rel = self;
                    };
                    taggedForDeletion = 0;
                    unread = 0;
                };
                from = "Suren.1@sc-msg1-msg.sc.sc";
                link =                     {
                    href = "http://1.1.1.1:80/services/messageboxes/63358/messages/<24346739.35.1328562602976.JavaMail.mango@sc-msg1-msg.sc.sc>";
                    rel = self;
                };
                parts =                     {
                    link =                         {
                        href = "http://1.1.1.1:80/services/messageboxes/63358/messages/<24346739.35.1328562602976.JavaMail.mango@sc-msg1-msg.sc.sc>/parts";
                        rel = self;
                    };
                    part =                         (
                                                    {
                            link =                                 {
                                href = "http://1.1.1.1:80/services/messageboxes/63358/messages/<24346739.35.1328562602976.JavaMail.mango@sc-msg1-msg.sc.sc>/parts/0";
                                rel = self;
                            };
                            mimeType = "TEXT/PLAIN";
                            name = "text.txt";
                            size = 6;
                        },
                                                    {
                            content =                                 {
                                href = "http://1.1.1.1:80/services/messageboxes/63358/messages/<24346739.35.1328562602976.JavaMail.mango@sc-msg1-msg.sc.sc>/parts/1/2c3a3400620f218d5378607260dc2749.wav";
                                rel = content;
                            };
                            duration = 3;
                            link =                                 {
                                href = "http://1.1.1.1:80/services/messageboxes/63358/messages/<24346739.35.1328562602976.JavaMail.mango@sc-msg1-msg.sc.sc>/parts/1";
                                rel = self;
                            };
                            mimeType = "AUDIO/WAV";
                            name = "Audio_Recording_S000551_002.wav";
                            size = 31190;
                        },
                                                    {
                            link =                                 {
                                href = "http://1.1.1.1:80/services/messageboxes/63358/messages/<24346739.35.1328562602976.JavaMail.mango@sc-msg1-msg.sc.sc>/parts/2";
                                rel = self;
                            };
                            mimeType = "APPLICATION/MS-TNEF";
                            name = "winmail.dat";
                            size = 656;
                        }
                    );
                };
                receivedDate = 1328562604000;
                sentDate = 1328562596000;
                subject = "Voice Message from Suren 1 (63357)";
            }
        );
    };
};
```

}

Comment: I think you should validate that you're trying to parse valid JSON first! Check out http://jsonlint.com/ or another validator to check your input first. Next, if you are using iOS 5, you can use `NSJSONSerialization`, otherwise you can use another library like https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit to do all the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the json is not valid. It should look more like this:

```
{
    "messages": {
        "link": {
            "href": "http: //1.1.1.1: 80/services/messageboxes/63358/messages",
            "rel": "self"
        }
    }
}
```

the '=' need to be ':' there are semicolons that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are correct the format is not valid. I tried using a couple of restful clients to issue the same request "SOAPUI" and "WizTools" and in both cases I receive valid XML back. However programmatically, using NSJSONSerialization the format returned is different and not valid. I'm thinking possibly a difference in encoding but at this point I don't know?

Comment: In fact, the JSON is a valid string when I retrieve it from the request. Its when I convert the string to an NSDictionary that the quotes and the colons are replaced which invalidates the JSON. Both the following methods render invalid JSON

Comment: In fact, the JSON is a valid string when I retrieve it from the request. Its when I convert the string to an NSDictionary that the quotes and the colons are replaced which invalidates the JSON. Both NSJSONSerialization:dataWithJSONObject and SBJSONParser objectwithData created NSDictionary objects with invalid JSON. I need to call the SBJSON NSDictionary category method JSONRepresentation to see valid format however the dictionary is not parseable?

Comment: found your problem. NSArray *messageBoxResponse = [responseDict objectForKey:@"messageBoxResponse"];
messageBoxResponce is a NSDictionary not an array.

Comment: So I'm good to go now. NSLog(@"JSON=: %@", responseDict.description); was not reporting the content correctly and was replacing colons with '=' and and removing quotes. If I do NSLog(@"JSON=: %@", responseDict.JSONRepresentation); I see correctly formatted JSON string output and yes I was parsing the wrong type of object. Not sure why description changes JSON format appearance though.. must be related to encoding...